# Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains a single, compatible version of javax.persistence.Table; Error creating bean

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven, jpa

Can anyone help me with this one? I already tried different solutions posted here but nothing works.

```
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

An attempt was made to call a method that does not exist. The attempt was made from the following location:

    org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.EntityBinder.processComplementaryTableDefinitions(EntityBinder.java:1239)

The following method did not exist:

    javax.persistence.Table.indexes()[Ljavax/persistence/Index;

The calling method's class, org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.EntityBinder, was loaded from the following location:

    jar:file:/C:/Users/csatl/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-core/5.6.5.Final/hibernate-core-5.6.5.Final.jar!/org/hibernate/cfg/annotations/EntityBinder.class

The called method's class, javax.persistence.Table, is available from the following locations:

    jar:file:/C:/Users/csatl/Desktop/Facultate/An%203-sem2/SD/labs/lab2/lib/javax.persistence.jar!/javax/persistence/Table.class
    jar:file:/C:/Users/csatl/.m2/repository/jakarta/persistence/jakarta.persistence-api/2.2.3/jakarta.persistence-api-2.2.3.jar!/javax/persistence/Table.class
    jar:file:/C:/Users/csatl/.m2/repository/javax/persistence/javax.persistence-api/2.2/javax.persistence-api-2.2.jar!/javax/persistence/Table.class
    jar:file:/C:/Users/csatl/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/javax/persistence/hibernate-jpa-2.1-api/1.0.0.Final/hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar!/javax/persistence/Table.class

The called method's class hierarchy was loaded from the following locations:

    javax.persistence.Table: file:/C:/Users/csatl/Desktop/Facultate/An%203-sem2/SD/labs/lab2/lib/javax.persistence.jar


Action:

Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains compatible versions of the classes org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.EntityBinder and javax.persistence.Table

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.Table.indexes()[Ljavax/persistence/Index;
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1804)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1154)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:908)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:740)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:415)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1312)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1301)
    at ro.sd.firstapp.FirstAppApplication.main(FirstAppApplication.java:11)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.Table.indexes()[Ljavax/persistence/Index;
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.EntityBinder.processComplementaryTableDefinitions(EntityBinder.java:1239)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.bindClass(AnnotationBinder.java:826)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.source.internal.annotations.AnnotationMetadataSourceProcessorImpl.processEntityHierarchies(AnnotationMetadataSourceProcessorImpl.java:225)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess$1.processEntityHierarchies(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:239)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:282)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1460)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1494)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1863)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1800)
    ... 16 more
```

Here is my pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.4</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>ro.sd</groupId>
    <artifactId>first-app</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>first-app</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <frontend-maven-plugin.version>1.6</frontend-maven-plugin.version>
        <node.version>v14.8.0</node.version>
        <yarn.version>v1.12.1</yarn.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-crypto</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.22</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.6.5.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.6.5.Final</version>
        </dependency>

<!--        <dependency>-->
<!--            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>-->
<!--            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>-->
<!--            <version>4.1.4.Final</version>-->
<!--        </dependency>-->
<!--        <dependency>-->
<!--            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>-->
<!--            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>-->
<!--            <version>5.2.3.Final</version>-->
<!--        </dependency>-->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
<!--        <dependency>-->
<!--            <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>-->
<!--            <artifactId>javax.persistence-api</artifactId>-->
<!--            <version>2.1</version>-->
<!--        </dependency>-->
<!--        <dependency>-->
<!--            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>-->
<!--            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>-->
<!--            <version>1.0.0.Final</version>-->
<!--        </dependency>-->

    </dependencies>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${project.parent.version}</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

The BeanCreationException is from my main class. I used a try catch.

```
package ro.sd.firstapp;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class FirstAppApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try{
            SpringApplication.run(FirstAppApplication.class, args);
        }catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

I tried changing the env variables. I tried including more dependencies, delete dependencies. I don't know what's wrong.

Here is my **mvn dependency:tree**

```
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:3.2.0:tree (default-cli) @ first-app ---
[INFO] ro.sd:first-app:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:jar:2.6.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop:jar:2.6.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:5.3.16:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:jar:1.9.7:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc:jar:2.6.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.zaxxer:HikariCP:jar:4.0.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:5.3.16:compile
[INFO] |  +- jakarta.transaction:jakarta.transaction-api:jar:1.3.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- jakarta.persistence:jakarta.persistence-api:jar:2.2.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:jar:2.6.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:jar:2.6.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:5.3.16:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:5.3.16:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:5.3.16:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:5.3.16:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.36:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-aspects:jar:5.3.16:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:2.6.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:2.6.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:2.6.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:jar:2.6.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.2.10:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.2.10:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-to-slf4j:jar:2.17.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.17.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.7.36:compile
[INFO] |  +- jakarta.annotation:jakarta.annotation-api:jar:1.3.5:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:5.3.16:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-jcl:jar:5.3.16:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.29:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-crypto:jar:5.6.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:jar:2.6.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-json:jar:2.6.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.13.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.13.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.13.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jdk8:jar:2.13.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:jar:2.13.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-parameter-names:jar:2.13.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:jar:2.6.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:jar:9.0.58:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-websocket:jar:9.0.58:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:5.3.16:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:5.3.16:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:5.3.16:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation:jar:2.6.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-el:jar:9.0.58:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.hibernate.validator:hibernate-validator:jar:6.2.2.Final:compile
[INFO] |     \- jakarta.validation:jakarta.validation-api:jar:2.0.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:jar:2.6.4:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test:jar:2.6.4:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test-autoconfigure:jar:2.6.4:test
[INFO] |  +- com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:jar:2.6.0:test
[INFO] |  |  \- net.minidev:json-smart:jar:2.4.8:test
[INFO] |  |     \- net.minidev:accessors-smart:jar:2.4.8:test
[INFO] |  |        \- org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:9.1:test
[INFO] |  +- jakarta.xml.bind:jakarta.xml.bind-api:jar:2.3.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- jakarta.activation:jakarta.activation-api:jar:1.2.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.assertj:assertj-core:jar:3.21.0:test
[INFO] |  +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest:jar:2.2:test
[INFO] |  +- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:jar:5.8.2:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:jar:5.8.2:test
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.opentest4j:opentest4j:jar:1.2.0:test
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.junit.platform:junit-platform-commons:jar:1.8.2:test
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.apiguardian:apiguardian-api:jar:1.1.2:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-params:jar:5.8.2:test
[INFO] |  |  \- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:jar:5.8.2:test
[INFO] |  |     \- org.junit.platform:junit-platform-engine:jar:1.8.2:test
[INFO] |  +- org.mockito:mockito-core:jar:4.0.0:test
[INFO] |  |  +- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy-agent:jar:1.11.22:test
[INFO] |  |  \- org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:3.2:test
[INFO] |  +- org.mockito:mockito-junit-jupiter:jar:4.0.0:test
[INFO] |  +- org.skyscreamer:jsonassert:jar:1.5.0:test
[INFO] |  |  \- com.vaadin.external.google:android-json:jar:0.0.20131108.vaadin1:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:5.3.16:test
[INFO] |  \- org.xmlunit:xmlunit-core:jar:2.8.4:test
[INFO] +- org.projectlombok:lombok:jar:1.18.22:compile
[INFO] +- mysql:mysql-connector-java:jar:8.0.28:runtime
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:5.6.5.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.4.3.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.persistence:javax.persistence-api:jar:2.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:jar:1.11.22:compile
[INFO] |  +- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.7:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction:jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec:jar:1.1.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss:jandex:jar:2.4.2.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:1.5.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.activation:javax.activation-api:jar:1.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:5.1.2.Final:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime:jar:2.3.6:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.glassfish.jaxb:txw2:jar:2.3.6:compile
[INFO] |     +- com.sun.istack:istack-commons-runtime:jar:3.0.12:compile
[INFO] |     \- com.sun.activation:jakarta.activation:jar:1.2.2:runtime
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:jar:5.6.5.Final:compile
[INFO] +- javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:jar:2.3.0:compile
[INFO] \- javax.persistence:persistence-api:jar:1.0.2:compile
```

Comment: `hibernate-core` already has dependency to `javax.persistence.api`. I dont think that you need to include this dep again in pom

Comment: I removed it, still getting the same error.

Comment: Remove the hibernate dependencies and the javax.persistence dependency. All of those are included in `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa`./

Comment: Still getting the same error. I tried running ```maven clean install``` and I get those error there too